# How to save image path using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences, mediastore

I have an activity that opens another activity to get a camera gallery pic. The picture comes back to my original activity and rest in an imageView. That's working fine. How do I save the image so when the user comes back later, or kills to app the image is still there. I know I am supposed the use Shared Preferences to get the image path and not save the image itself but I just don't know how do that.

Activity A

```
private ImageView im1;
private String selectedImagePath;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
    im1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    }}}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    };
   ((Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button3))
   .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }});
```

Activity B

```
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {              
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("image",R.id.showImg);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            finish();

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }}}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `onPause()` method in `Activity` with an image (to understand why `onPause`, check life cycle of an Activity diagram here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    SharedPrefrences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 0); // Open SharedPreferences with name AppSharedPref
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("ImagePath", selectedImagePath); // Store selectedImagePath with key "ImagePath". This key will be then used to retrieve data.         
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}
```

It means that whenever this `Activity` goes into background, the image path will be saved in `SharedPreferences` with name `AppSharedPref` - this name can be whatever you like, but you need to use the same one when retrieving data.

Then override `onResume()` method in the same `Activity` so that you can retrieve image path when `Activity` comes to foreground:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 0);
    selectedImagePath = settings.getString("ImagePath", "");
    super.onResume();
}
```

You may also want to play with overriding other methods, like for example `onStart()` according to diagram, but this I leave to you.

Comment: I tried to implement this into my code but I must be putting this in the wrong place. Doesnt the onPause then OnResume sections go right after onActivityResult section?

Comment: No matter where you actually put this, it just has to be inside `Activity`. Yes, it can be after `onActivityResult()`. What is wrong with that?

Comment: I marked this the correct answer because I know it's the right way to things even if I cant get it. I have posted another question using what you gave me. Still cant save, maybe you can help.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358820/how-to-save-multiple-images-to-imageview-using-shared-preferences

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a comment there for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "selectedImagePath" in passing intents from one Activity to another.

in Activity A.

Intent intent = new Intent(this , Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("imagePath", selectedImagePath );

and to get it in Activity B,

String strImagePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imagePath");

Answer (score 1):

```
String imagePath = ... ;

SharedPrefrences prefs = getSharedPreferences("application_settings", 0);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("image_path", imagePath);              
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String path = prefs.getString("key", default value);
```

To edit and save preferences

```
prefs.edit().putString("key", value).commit();
```