# How to Save multiple images to ImageView using Shared Preferences

Tags: android

I have a activity with a couple of ImageViews. The user can LongPress an ImageView and they have the option of getting any image from the camera gallery. I am trying to save the imagepath of those images so that when the user closes and opens the app again the image will still be in the imageView. I dont understand why this isn't working.

Here is my Activity A where the imageView is

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
    im1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);}}}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);};

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1); // Open SharedPreferences with name AppSharedPref
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("ImagePath", selectedImagePath); // Store selectedImagePath with key "ImagePath". This key will be then used to retrieve data.         
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
    }   

protected void onResume1() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1);
    selectedImagePath = sp.getString("ImagePath", "");
    super.onResume();
    }
```

And Activity B gets the cam gallery pic and sends back to Activity A

```
 Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("image",R.id.showImg);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            finish();  }
            });
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }}}
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Why did you create `onResume1()`? I told you to override `onResume()` method (not to create another one) as well as you did with `onPause()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1);
    selectedImagePath = sp.getString("ImagePath", "");
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
    im1.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    super.onResume();
}
```

instead of:

```
protected void onResume1() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1);
    selectedImagePath = sp.getString("ImagePath", "");
    super.onResume();
}
```

Because your activity extends `Activity` class, which has this method declared and implemented. This method is called after `Activity` returns to foreground. What you want is to override this method so that it does what you want it to do.

Comment: I must be doing something else wrong in code. This should work but's it not. Im very new at this and I'm trying to reach to far too soon. I need to learn more about android programming before I can implement something like this in my app. Maybe I'll do it in version 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Indeed you have to, but method overriding is a java concept, not android itself. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. I get picture to ImageView. I go to another page come back and it's gone.

Comment: Are you familiar with debugging process? If yes, you could put breakpoint inside `onResume()` method and see if you're getting proper `selectedImagePath`. I also updated my answer, please try to use edited code.